# plotting dates in matplotlib with NaN values

Tags: python, datetime, matplotlib

I have found many questions on this subject, but I still cannot understand the basic steps to plot date information in python.

My timeseries is

```
 >>> datetime_series.shape
(8736,)
>>> datetime_series
array([datetime.datetime(1979, 1, 2, 0, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1979, 1, 2, 1, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1979, 1, 2, 2, 0), ...,
       datetime.datetime(1979, 12, 31, 21, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1979, 12, 31, 22, 0),
       datetime.datetime(1979, 12, 31, 23, 0)], dtype=object)
```

My data is

```
 >>> data.shape
(8736,)   
#contains np.nan values!!!
```

My code right now (my commented out is what I have tried...)

```
fig,ax1 = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(datetime_series,data)
#plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m'))
#plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
#plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
#ax1.set_xlim([datetime_series[0],datetime_series[-1])
ax1.set_ylabel('Cumulative windspeed over open water [m/s]')
#ax1.set_xlim( ### how do I do this??
plt.title('My title')
fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This produces a blank plot.

If anyone can walk me through the steps of plotting datetime , I just don't understand where to start, becuase it seems like the documentation and the stackoverflow answers all have different methods.. (for example, using plot_date versus just plt.plot()

Comment: There is an [official example](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/api/date_demo.html) on how to use dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your data isn't being graphed - it should work even with NaN values. Check out this example, you can look at **data** and **datetime_series** to see how they compare to your data. As stated in the comments there is an official example on how to use dates in matplotlib - which would definitely be worth looking at.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
import numpy as np

# Generate some dummy data
N = 500
year = np.random.randint(1950,2000,N)
month = np.random.randint(1,12,N)
day = np.random.randint(1,28,N)

datatime_series = np.array([datetime.datetime(*(dd+(0,0))) for dd in zip(year, month, day)])
datatime_series.sort()

data = np.random.random(N)*20000 + (np.linspace(1950,2000,N)/10.)**2

# Now add some NaNs
for i in np.random.randint(0,N-1,int(N/10)):
    data[i]=np.nan

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ax.plot(datatime_series, data)
ax.set_ylim(0,1.2*ax.get_ylim()[1])
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fig.show()
```

[image]